# Is it necessary to add "on it" to the end of "This PC has Windows 10 installed (on it)"

Tags: passive-voice

> 1. This PC has Windows 10 installed (on it).
> 2. This memory card has games stored (on it).

I have seen two versions of these sentences; one has "on it", the other doesn't have. Please could you advise me on which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting examples.

The first does not need "**on it**"

> This PC has Windows 10 installed.

is perfectly fine since "**installed**" implies "**on/in it**".

However, in

> This memory card has games stored *on it*.

"**on it**" is more necessary if you are going to use "**stored**".

The latter case is usually said as

> This memory card has games *on it*.

where "**stored**" would be repetitive, or

> This memory card **contains** games.

Comment: When "store " is used instead of "contain" or  "has", is "on/in it" necessary? This memory card stores games (on/in it).

Comment: "The memory card **stores** games *(on/in it)*." talks about a *capability* of the memory card, but does not say anything about its contents.